# Inner Class with Compare Method from Comparator JAVA

Tags: java, collections, compare, comparator, inner-classes

For a certain project I have to order some figures by area and name. First they are ordered by area from largest to smallest and if they coincide, they are ordered alphabetically. In a class called `RectangularRegion` I have an inner class of the following type:

```
//Inner Class
static class RectangularRegionComparator implements Comparator<RectangularRegion>{
    @Override
    public int compare(RectangularRegiono1, RectangularRegiono2) {
        //Return a positive integer if the area of ​​o1 is higher than o2 [we want o1 to go before o2 (o1 <o2)], a negative is o1 and less than o2 and 0 are equal, then we will sort by name from A to Z
        if ((o1.Area() - o2.Area()) != 0){
            return o1.Area() - o2.Area();   
        }
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
}
```

How should I do if from another class I want to sort a set of `RectangularRegion`? I thought the best way would be the following, but it fails (`The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<RectangularRegion>, RectangularRegion.RectangularRegionComparator)`):

```
public void ordenarRegionesXAreaAsc(){
    Collections.sort(rex, new RectangularRegion.RectangularRegionComparator());
}
```

Where `private Collection<RegionRectangular> rex= new ArrayList<RectangularRegion>();`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which is the type returned by the method `Area`?

Comment: It is an int @dariosicily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sort a `Collection` because this interface does not impose an order on its elements.

Instead declare

```
private List<RegionRectangular> rex= new ArrayList<RectangularRegion>();
```

---

**Side Notes**

Since Java 1.8, the `Comparator` class has some convenience methods that allow you to set up a `Comparator` instance without implementing the interface.

For example you could do

```
// instead of class RectangualarRegionComparator
static final Comparator<RectangularRegion> NATURAL_ORDER =
     Comparator.comparing(RectangularRegion::Area)
               .thenComparing(region -> region.name);

// or to avoid auto-boxing
static final Comparator<RectangularRegion> NATURAL_ORDER =
     Comparator.comparing(region -> Integer.valueOf(region.Area()))
               .thenComparing(region -> region.name);
```

and

```
public void ordenarRegionesXAreaAsc() {
    Collections.sort(rex, RectangularRegion.NATURAL_ORDER);
}
```